# Reverse for 'products_category' with keyword arguments '{'products_po_category': <QuerySet [<Product: Maybach>]>}' not found

Tags: python, django

Hi I need to implement the following:
I have a form with a category selection, and based on the selected category, I need to redirect the user to a page with products for this category.

URLS.PY

```
from django.urls import path
from first.views import productsHTML, productHTML, products_category

urlpatterns = [

    path("products_category", products_category, name = "products_category"),
    path("productsHTML/<str:uuid>", productHTML, name = "productHTML"),
    path("productsHTML/", productsHTML, name = "productsHTML"),

]
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .models import Product
from .forms import CategoryChoice

def productsHTML(request):
    form = CategoryChoice(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        category = form.cleaned_data['category']
        products_po_category = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
        
        return redirect('products_category', products_po_category=products_po_category, permanent=True)
    all_products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'products': all_products,
    }
    return render(request, "products.html", context) 

def products_category(request,products_po_category):
    context = {
        "products_po_category": products_po_category
    }
    return render(request, "product_category.html", context)
```

Through form.cleaned_data['category'] I get data about the selected category and then, through Product.objects.filter(category=category) I get the objects of this category and after all this I redirect to the page with the products of this category, passing the list of objects of the selected categories.

FORMS.PY

```
from django import forms

from .models import Product

class CategoryChoice(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('category',)
        widgets = {
            'category': forms.Select(),
        }
```

full text of the error:
Reverse for 'products_category' with keyword arguments '{'products_po_category': <QuerySet [<Product: Maybach>]>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products_category\Z']

I will be glad for any help! If you need more information, I'm ready to provide.
Thank you.

Comment: the url `path("products_category", products_category, name = "products_category")` defines no arguments

Comment: also... `path("productsHTML/<str:uuid>", productHTML, name = "productHTML")` defines one argument, but the view function you've connected it to does not take an argument: `def productsHTML(request)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no argument for **products_category** url.

You are creating views in wrong way. In **productsHTML**
view redirect with category_id argument and filter Products in **products_category** view.

Your **productsHTML** will like this:

```
def productsHTML(request):
    form = CategoryChoice(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        category = form.cleaned_data['category']
        return redirect('products_category', category_id=category_id, permanent=True)
    all_products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'products': all_products,
    }
    return render(request, "products.html", context)
```

**products_category** view will be:

```
def products_category(request,category_id):
    products_po_category = Product.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)
    context = {
        "products_po_category": products_po_category
    }
    return render(request, "product_category.html", context)
```

**urls.py** will be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("products_category/<int:category_id>/", products_category, name = "products_category"),
    path("productsHTML/<str:uuid>/", productHTML, name = "productHTML"),
    path("productsHTML/", productsHTML, name = "productsHTML"),
]
```

Try this code.